# How to add many indexed arrays together under each other?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have some indexed arrays like this

```
 f[1] = ConstantArray[a, {2, 3}]
 f[2] = ConstantArray[b, {2, 3}]
 f[3] = ConstantArray[c, {2, 3}]
```

I wanna add them together from below, I can do like this

```
 ArrayFlatten[{{f[1]}, {f[2]}, {f[3]}}]
```

Giving result a 3 x 6 matrix

How to generalize ArrayFlatten process so can work for arbitarily large number of arrays f[n]?

So result is 3 x n matrix with n a large numba

Comment: `Flatten[f /@ Range[3], 1]` or `Join @@ (f /@ Range[3])`. In the general case, replace the 3 with the number of arrays you have. Note that the dimensions of the result of `ArrayFlatten` is 6 x 3, not 3x6. I tried to reproduce the results of `ArrayFlatten` anyway.

Comment: Why not f[1] + f[2] + f[3]  ?

Comment: Try e.g.: `    joinarrays[n_] := Flatten[Table[f[i], {i, n}], 1];     
    joinarrays[3]`